# Probability of being within one standard deviation of mean given only a moment generating function

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, actuarial-science

I am trying to figure out how to approach this:

[image]

For starters, I calculated M'(0) and M"(0), which allowed me to find the mean and variance. I got 2 for the mean and 1.6 for the variance. But now, since I don't know what the distribution looks like (and I'm not sure if this MGF can be easily arranged to look like one for a familiar distribution), I am stumped. Is there something very easy here that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: this MGF is indeed that of a distribution that should be familiar to you.

Further hint: $9765625 = 5^{10}$.

Comment: Just how much rearrangement am I going to need to do here? I am still not seeing the distribution...doesn't immediately look exponential, poisson, binomial...

Comment: Why doesn't it look like binomial?

Comment: This is the MGF for binomial (I'm pretty sure): (1+(-1+e^t) p)^n  I suppose it could be rearranged, but I am having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Then MGF of a binomial is given as $$ \left(Pe^t + q\right)^n.$$ You are given $$M(t) = \frac{\left(e^t+4\right)^{10}}{9765625},$$ but the $9765625 = 5^{10}.$ 
So $$M(t) = \frac{\left(e^t+4\right)^{10}}{5^{10}}= \left(\frac{e^t +4}{5}\right)^{10}=\left( \frac{1}{5}e^t+\frac{4}{5}\right)^{10}.$$ From this, you get that $p=0.2,~q=0.8,~ n=10$.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hmm...it looks like this still leaves me with trying to find binomial probability for decimals. Do I just have to interpolate here?

Comment: You want $P(\mu-\sigma<X<\mu+\sigma)$= the sum of the probabilities that $X$ is an integer between the interval $(\mu-\sigma, \mu+\sigma)$

Comment: Ah! Thank you! The question now would just be to determine which integers those are, which is very clear :-)